# Which are some of the PHP error detection and syntax highlight in Eclipse that aren't present in Vim?

Tags: php, eclipse, vim

I'm a Vim user, and I always encounter php errors that I just can't see in Vim.

Which are some of the PHP error detection and syntax highlight in Eclipse (does Eclipse have better syntax highlight than Vim?) that aren't present in Vim (clean install both)?

EDIT: Is Eclipse's PHP code completion far more advanced than Vim's?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what you mean by 'far more advanced' but you can always use [Eclim](http://eclim.org/) to run Eclipse in headless mode so you can access its code completion from within Vim.